# Make a Java Applet work on a Web Page [Eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, processing

I am running processing code on Eclipse by using the necessary libraries.

I am attempting to get my Java Applet on eclipse to work on a web page.  I tried creating a .jar file for the java applet and then run it from an HTML document but it just will not run.

The program runs perfectly on Eclipse, but I can't seem to convert it correctly

This is my html code

```
<applet code="pRobot.class" archive="pRobot.jar,controlP5.jar,net.jar,core.jar" width="205" height="480">
<param name="image" value="loading.gif"><param name="centerimage" value="true"><param name="codebase_lookup" value="false">
</applet>
```

Here is an image showing all my libraries and java file
http://oi62.tinypic.com/9lhjwk.jpg

I could really use some help.  This is giving me a huge headache.

Here is my Java Code

```
import processing.core.*; 
import controlP5.*; 
import processing.net.*; 


public class pRobot extends PApplet {

/**
 * Image button. 
 * 
 * Loading images and using them to create a button. 
 */


long timer;                  
long interval = 100;         


ControlP5 controlP5;

Client myClient; 

ImageButtons turnLeft;
ImageButtons turnRight;
ImageButtons holdForward;
ImageButtons holdReverse;
ImageButtons stepForward;
ImageButtons stepReverse;
ImageButtons spinLeft;
ImageButtons spinRight;
ImageButtons spinLeftStep;
ImageButtons spinRightStep;
ImageButtons camUp;
ImageButtons camDown;


int straight     = 1;
int straightstep = 1;
int outerturn    = 1;
int innerturn    = 1;
int spinhold     = 1;
int spinstep     = 1;

int sliderOffsetX = 20;
int sliderOffsetY = 220;
int sliderWidth   = 100;
int sliderHeight  = 10;

String[] forwardArray = new String[8];
String[] reverseArray = new String[8];

String lastData = "";

public void setup()
{
  size(205, 480);
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, 205, 205);

  timer = interval + millis();  // set timer


  controlP5 = new ControlP5(this);

  myClient = new Client(this, "10.12.79.195", 2000); 

  controlP5.setColorLabel(0x00ff0000);
  controlP5.setColorValue(0xffffffff);
  controlP5.setColorForeground(0xffff0000);
  controlP5.setColorBackground(0xff660000);

  forwardArray[0] = "08";
  forwardArray[1] = "01";
  forwardArray[2] = "02";
  forwardArray[3] = "03";
  forwardArray[4] = "04";
  forwardArray[5] = "05";
  forwardArray[6] = "06";
  forwardArray[7] = "07";

  reverseArray[0] = "08";
  reverseArray[1] = "15";
  reverseArray[2] = "14";
  reverseArray[3] = "13";
  reverseArray[4] = "12";
  reverseArray[5] = "11";
  reverseArray[6] = "10";
  reverseArray[7] = "09";

  Slider s1 = controlP5.addSlider("straight",          0, 7, 1, sliderOffsetX, sliderOffsetY + 0,   sliderWidth, sliderHeight);
  Slider s2 = controlP5.addSlider("straightstep",      0, 7, 1, sliderOffsetX, sliderOffsetY + 30,  sliderWidth, sliderHeight);
  Slider s3 = controlP5.addSlider("outerturn",         0, 7, 1, sliderOffsetX, sliderOffsetY + 60,  sliderWidth, sliderHeight);
  Slider s4 = controlP5.addSlider("innerturn",         0, 7, 1, sliderOffsetX, sliderOffsetY + 90,  sliderWidth, sliderHeight);
  Slider s5 = controlP5.addSlider("spinhold",          0, 7, 1, sliderOffsetX, sliderOffsetY + 120, sliderWidth, sliderHeight);
  Slider s6 = controlP5.addSlider("spinstep",          0, 7, 1, sliderOffsetX, sliderOffsetY + 150, sliderWidth, sliderHeight);

  s1.captionLabel().set("Straight");
  s1.captionLabel().toUpperCase(false);
  s2.captionLabel().set("Straight Step");
  s2.captionLabel().toUpperCase(false);
  s3.captionLabel().set("Outer Turn");
  s3.captionLabel().toUpperCase(false);
  s4.captionLabel().set("Inner Turn");
  s4.captionLabel().toUpperCase(false);
  s5.captionLabel().set("Spin Hold");
  s5.captionLabel().toUpperCase(false);
  s6.captionLabel().set("Spin Step");
  s6.captionLabel().toUpperCase(false);

  s1.setNumberOfTickMarks(8);
  s2.setNumberOfTickMarks(8);
  s3.setNumberOfTickMarks(8);
  s4.setNumberOfTickMarks(8);
  s5.setNumberOfTickMarks(8);
  s6.setNumberOfTickMarks(8);

  PImage imgUp    = loadImage("controlpanelup.png");
  PImage imgHover = loadImage("controlpanelhover.png");
  PImage imgDown  = loadImage("controlpaneldown.png");

  turnLeft      = new ImageButtons(0  , 0  , 77, 78, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  turnRight     = new ImageButtons(129, 0  , 79, 78, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  holdForward   = new ImageButtons(78 , 0  , 50, 49, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  holdReverse   = new ImageButtons(78 , 158, 50, 50, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  spinLeft      = new ImageButtons(0  , 79 , 49, 50, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  spinRight     = new ImageButtons(158, 79 , 50, 50, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  spinLeftStep  = new ImageButtons(50 , 79 , 29, 50, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  spinRightStep = new ImageButtons(129, 79 , 28, 50, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  stepForward   = new ImageButtons(78 , 50 , 50, 30, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  stepReverse   = new ImageButtons(78 , 128, 50, 28, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  camUp         = new ImageButtons(0  , 128, 77, 78, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);
  camDown       = new ImageButtons(129, 128, 79, 78, imgUp, imgHover, imgDown);

}

public void draw()
{
  turnLeft.update("z" + forwardArray[outerturn] + reverseArray[innerturn] + "1x", "z08080x");
  turnLeft.display();
  turnRight.update("z" + forwardArray[innerturn] + reverseArray[outerturn] + "1x", "z08080x");
  turnRight.display();

  holdForward.update("z" + forwardArray[straight] + reverseArray[straight] + "1x", "z08080x");
  holdForward.display();
  holdReverse.update("z" + reverseArray[straight] + forwardArray[straight] + "1x", "z08080x");
  holdReverse.display();

  stepForward.update("z" + forwardArray[straightstep] + reverseArray[straightstep] + "0x", "");
  stepForward.display();
  stepReverse.update("z" + reverseArray[straightstep] + forwardArray[straightstep] + "0x", "");
  stepReverse.display();

  spinLeft.update("z" + forwardArray[spinhold] + forwardArray[spinhold] + "1x", "z08080x");
  spinLeft.display();
  spinRight.update("z" + reverseArray[spinhold] + reverseArray[spinhold] + "1x", "z08080x");
  spinRight.display();

  spinLeftStep.update("z" + forwardArray[spinstep] + forwardArray[spinstep] + "0x", "");
  spinLeftStep.display();
  spinRightStep.update("z" + reverseArray[spinstep] + reverseArray[spinstep] + "0x", "");
  spinRightStep.display();

  camUp.update("zu", "zs");
  camUp.display();
  camDown.update("zd", "zs");
  camDown.display();

}

class Button
{
  int x, y;
  int w, h;
  int basecolor, highlightcolor;
  int currentcolor;
  boolean over = false;
  boolean pressed = false;
  boolean mouseWasDown = false;

  public void pressed() {
    if(over && mousePressed) {
      pressed = true;
    } else {
      pressed = false;
    }    
  }

  public boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
}

class ImageButtons extends Button 
{
  PImage base;
  PImage roll;
  PImage down;
  PImage currentimage;
  String downValue;
  String upValue;

  ImageButtons(int ix, int iy, int iw, int ih, PImage ibase, PImage iroll, PImage idown) 
  {
    x = ix;
    y = iy;
    w = iw;
    h = ih;
    base = ibase.get(ix, iy, iw, ih);
    roll = iroll.get(ix, iy, iw, ih);
    down = idown.get(ix, iy, iw, ih);
    currentimage = base;
  }

  public void update(String sDownValue, String sUpValue) 
  {
    if(!pressed){
      downValue = sDownValue;
    }
    upValue = sUpValue;
    over();
    pressed();
    if(pressed) {
      if(!mouseWasDown){
        //send on command
        myClient.write(downValue);
        println(downValue);
        mouseWasDown = true;
      }
      currentimage = down;
    } else if (over){
      currentimage = roll;
    } else {
      currentimage = base;
    }

    if(!pressed && mouseWasDown){
      //send off command
      myClient.write(upValue);
      println(upValue);

      mouseWasDown = false;
    }
  }

  public void over() 
  {
    if( overRect(x, y, w, h) ) {
      over = true;
    } else {
      over = false;
    }
  }

  public void display() 
  {
    image(currentimage, x, y);
  }
}




  static public void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main(new String[] { "--bgcolor=#F0F0F0", "RoboControl3" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your code here not a link to a picture. Also explain how it wont work

Comment: I added my Java code.  It just won't show up on the webpage.  The applet doesn't appear.  The jar file contains the images so that shouldn't be the problem.  I think I'm exporting the code incorrectly or something.

Comment: see if there are messages in java console...

Comment: There is a tool to export applets from Processing IDE, maybe if you try it, you can see how the final result looks like...

Comment: What does your Java Console say when you try to run the applet? Info on running the Java Console: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml